# Opencart How to display Product tag(s) in category listing page?

Tags: opencart

OpenCart 1.5.3.1: How to display Product tag(s) in category listing page?

Answer (score 1):

In catalog/category controller add a new index `'tag'  => $result['tag'],` in array `$this->data['products'][]` (around line:187). This will make product tag accessible in product/category.tpl.

Answer (score 1):

**MODEL:**

In `/catalog/model/catalog/category.php` file you can have this custom code to get all tags with respect to the `category_id`

```
public function getTags($category_id) {
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT tag FROM " . DB_PREFIX .
    "product_description opd LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX .
    "product_to_category optc ON optc.product_id = opd.product_id
     WHERE opd.tag <> '' AND optc.category_id = '".(int)$category_id."'");
    return $query->rows;
}
```

**CONTROLLER:**

In `/catalog/controller/product/category.php` file you can call the above model method

```
$tags = $this->model_catalog_category->getTags($category_id);
$data['tags'] = array();
if($tags) {
    foreach($tags as $tag) {
        $tag_names = explode(',', $tag['tag']);
        foreach ($tag_names as $tag_name) {
            if(!in_array($tag_name, $data['tags'])) {
                $data['tags'][] = trim($tag_name);
            }
        }               
    }
} else {
    $data['tags'] = '';
}
```

**TEMPLATE:**

In the template you can access the tags in variable `$tags`